# object created with "new" keywords and the object created with "Object.create" gives different result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain to me why object created with "**new**" keywords and the object created with "**Object.create**" keywords gives different result?

```
function Car (desc) {
this.desc = 'test';
this.color = "red";
}

Car.prototype.getInfo = function() {
  return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
}

//if i create object with "new" it's alert "A blue test"
var car =  new Car();
car.color = "blue";
alert(car.getInfo());  //A blue test

// but if i create object with it's alert "A blue undefined"
var car =  Object.create(Car.prototype);
car.color = "blue";
alert(car.getInfo()); //A blue undefined
```

Comment: Car's prototype does not have `color` property. So the second `car` does not have `color`.

Comment: Do this on node console. And then log the first car, you will understand the structure.

Comment: This may help you,,, http://jsfiddle.net/jvms3uph/1/

Comment: i am getting color property when use "Object.create" but "desc" property is undefined.but if i used "new" property of color & desc is showing.see my question properly

Comment: @CMS can you help me out in this question :)

Answer (score 1):

These two pieces of code are (usually) equivalent:

```
var car = new Car();
```

And:

```
var car = Object.create(Car.prototype);
Car.call(car);  // this second line is missing from your code
```

In your code, the constructor does not run, so those properties do not get set.

Comment: if i use your way "Car.call(car);" then every thing is shows undefined.even my color value is undefined which is previously showed :)

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Object.create is for inheritance.
The 'new' keyword is to create an object instance of a prototype definition.

So when using Object.create in your example, it is the Prototype of Car and not an instance of Car.

Comment: _"it is the Prototype of Car and not an instance of Car."_ - no, that's not correct. It simply is a `Car` on which the constructor has not been run.